# What are the methods except Bag Of Words (TF-IDF) for converting textual features into numerical features?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, random-forest, tf-idf

I have been working on Natural Language Processing these days. My aim is to classify different words in a multi-lingual sentence written in Roman Script based on some criteria. Thus, I need a classifier for it. Unquestionably, there are many. But since my features aren't numerical but textual, and most of the classifiers like Support Vector Machine (SVM) input numerical features, I looked for some methodology to convert my textual features into numerical one. Though the concept of Bag Of Words with the use of Term Frequency and Inverse Document Frequency (TF-IDF) is a generic approach for this purpose, one of my textual feature, namely local context, is of fixed length and i want to know if it is possible to convert it into numerical feature without using TF-IDF. Local context feature refers to considering previous two and next two words (which comprise the context of a particular word). Therefore, I am looking for any other methodology which could prove to be better in this case. I found similar query at Cross Validated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144327/convert-categorical-data-into-numerical-data), but that is for document clustering and i want to classify individual words into different classes. I also found one unanswered similar [question](https://www.quora.com/What-are-different-techniques-for-converting-qualitative-features-into-numerical-features-for-machine-learning-algorithms) on quora.

To serve my purpose, I want either the textual feature to be converted into numerical one or a classifier that can take textual features as input. Is there any one who could help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is really, how do I enumerate the possible inputs?  This is one of those rare situations where really "the only real limit is your imagination".  But a simple approach is to just catalog the possible permutations, and assign a number to each.

With a riduculously small lexicon, you could assign a number to each possible permutation of the words in the lexicon.  If your vocabulary is {'bag', 'of', 'words'} you could assign the numbers

```
1 bag of words
2 bag words of
3 of bag words
4 of words bag
5 words bag of
6 words of bag
```

and perhaps a few more to cater for an empty slot.  But for a large dictionary, clearly this isn't feasible.  Perhaps if you instead assign a number identifier to each word:

```
1 bag
2 of
3 words
```

then you can do something like *(1 * 100) + (2 * 10) + (1 * 3)* to obtain the number 123 for the permutation "bag of words".  Or if you want to emphasize the context, maybe assign binary features, and apply a multiplier to the central word:

```
001 bag
010 of
100 words
```

would obtain *(1 * 001) + (1000 * 010) + (1 * 100)* = 010101 = 21 for the head word 'of' surrounded by the leading context 'bag' and the trailing context 'words'.

What makes sense depends on your application.  It's easy to come up with niche applications where it might make sense to count the number of occurrences of the letter *b* or whatever, and simply directly use the metric you are interested in as the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't have to use TF-IDF with bag of words (a simple count vector would work, for example), but it is meant to help select the words which are most useful in classification.

It's a bit difficult to help without more information as to what classification you are attempting to make, but a few other approaches might be to look at the n-grams around a word, to perform sentiment analysis of the surrounding words, or to extract topic distributions of words using LDA and use those vectors as features. (These are all approaches to converting textual data into useful numerical features- there aren't really classifiers that work on raw text.)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, a bag-of-words is a representation of a **text**.

To represent a **word** you can use a bag-of-letters, letter n-grams or similar things. Another idea is to classify words by looking at their left and right neighbours (represented as bag-of words).